# when make elf, link is fail. post R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 error

Tags: gcc, linker, llvm, ld, elf

in my asm code, i use **_bss_begin**

```
adr x0, _bss_begin
adr x1, _bss_end
```

which is defined in link.ld

```
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xffff000000000000;
    .text.boot : { *(.text.boot) }
    . = ALIGN(0x00001000);
    user_begin = .;
    .text.user : { build/user* (.text) }
    .rodata.user : { build/user* (.rodata) }
    .data.user : { build/user* (.data) }
    .bss.user : { build/user* (.bss) }
    user_end = .;
    .text :  { *(.text) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata) }
    .data : { *(.data) }
    . = ALIGN(0x8);
    _bss_begin = .;
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } 
    _bss_end = .;
    . = ALIGN(0x00001000);
    pg_dir = .;
    .data.pgd : { . += (3 * (1 << 12)); }
}
```

but when build , it post error msg

```
relocation truncated to fit: R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_LO21 against symbol `_bss_end' defined in .bss section
```

any body can get some suggest about this error msg ?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this proble, i use cmd file to check .bss section size,finaly found problem

[image]

which array is too big in mm.c.
after modify it, link pass.